# ListView not showing default pressed color

Tags: android, listview, dialog

I added a custom dialog with only a simple listView inside.

I don't get selection color (which normally appears in list view without any additional setup) while pressing an item. Click listener works, etc. But not color.

Also tried setting explicitly a selector:

```
list.setSelector(R.color.blue);
```

But it doesn't happen anything. Tried also setting different background colors for the list, still no selection color.

Comment: Please post the XML in your drawable.

Comment: do you tried `android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with the color resource you created because I am able to change the color on selection of a list item, embedded in a custom dialog, using `list.setSelector(R.color.blue);`.

Comment: setSelector() was just a try to get some color working. I'm talking about the default color which is shown on lists while pressed. Edited the post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue. Fixed it with adding:

```
StateListDrawable drawable = new StateListDrawable();
drawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

to `ListView`'s adapter `getView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm late to answering this question but I found the actual answer in case anyone in the future is searching for the answer. The other two answers here did not work.

So I have a ListView that has a custom ListView row with drawables as their background. Doing this made it so that the default PRESSED grayish highlight didn't flash and turn on, like when you're doing a long press. What is happening is that the ListView is drawing the selector, if you have one, beneath the View. Here's how you fix it:

Up in the onCreate:

```
// this sets the selector/pressed drawable or you could use a color or whatever
listView.setSelector(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listviewrow_pressed));

// this draws the selector drawable/color on top
listView.setDrawSelectorOnTop(true);
```